# Analyser.getFloatTimeDomainData() does not exist in Safari

Tags: javascript, ios, safari, mobile-safari

Apparently Safari's Analyser node does not have the getFloatTimeDomainData method [Here you can see the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4mepS.png). I'm looking for a similar function that copies the current waveform, or time-domain, data into a Float32Array and will work on safari's browser.

```
window.AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
var buflen = 1024;
var buf = new Float32Array( buflen );
audioContext = new AudioContext();
MAX_SIZE = Math.max(4,Math.floor(audioContext.sampleRate/5000));
navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia ||
                   navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
                   navigator.mozGetUserMedia ||
                   navigator.msGetUserMedia;

navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio: true})
        .then(function(stream) {
      gotStreamPre(stream);
    });

 function gotStreamPre(stream) {
  // Create an AudioNode from the stream.
  mediaStreamSource = audioContext.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
  // Connect it to the destination.
  analyser = audioContext.createAnalyser();
  analyser.fftSize = 2048;
  mediaStreamSource.connect( analyser );
  updatePitchPre();
 }

function updatePitchPre( time ) {
  if(analyser!=null){
     var cycles = new Array;
     analyser.getFloatTimeDomainData( buf );//not working on Safari
     var ac = autoCorrelatePre( buf , audioContext.sampleRate );
  if (ac > -1) {

    }
  if (!window.requestAnimationFrame)
       window.requestAnimationFrame = window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame;
       rafID = window.requestAnimationFrame( updatePitchPre );
   }
}
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AnalyserNode/getFloatTimeDomainData#Browser_compatibility Sounds like safari is supported, though (mobile devices aside). Can you please add further informations about "not working"? what happens exactly?

Comment: @briosheje I added the Unhandled Promise Rejection error to my question.

Comment: Try replacing `audioContext = new AudioContext();` with `audioContext  = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();`

Comment: @briosheje but i have it... first line

Comment: you edited the original code, it originally was `audioContext = new AudioContext();`, I can see that in the edit history. If that doesn't work in that way, can you please add: `console.log(analyser)`?

Comment: @briosheje The console output: AnalyserNode {fftSize: 2048, frequencyBinCount: 1024, minDecibels: -100, maxDecibels: -30, smoothingTimeConstant: 0.8, …}

Comment: Does the log have any `getFloatTimeDomainData` inside it? Also, where is `buf` coming from?

Comment: @briosheje yes, there's getFloatTimeDomainData inside it. the buf comes from `var buflen = 1024;
var buf = new Float32Array( buflen );`

Comment: Unfortunately, Safari's webkitAudioContext (AudioContext) implementation is severely outdated and appearently unmaintained, and misses many, many new features and revisions to the W3C specification, and also has a lot of bugs that do not get attention. We've struggled with our in-development web-based DAW (Digital Audio Workstation) for many years now and have lost all hope that Apple will some day get their act together.

Answer (score 1):

I have same problem, you can add this:

```
if (analyser && !analyser.getFloatTimeDomainData) {
    var r = new Uint8Array(2048);
    analyser.getFloatTimeDomainData = function(e) {
        analyser.getByteTimeDomainData(r);
        for (var t = 0, o = e.length; o > t; t++) e[t] = .0078125 * (r[t] - 128)
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you explain why use these specific numbers e.g. `.0078125` and `128`, please?